# Sub-queries in fields and where in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I dot that in CakePHP?
I try everything I know, but doesn't work:

```
        select
            card_type
            ,sum (case when used = 'Y' then (select amount from auth a1 where a1.origid = a.pnref and trxtype = 'D') else amount end) as total
        from    auth a
        where
            add_date between '$this->date1' and '$this->date2'
            and     (trxtype = 'S' or trxtype = 'F')
            and     user_num = $this->user_num
            and     pnref not in (select    origid
                                    from        auth a
                                    where       add_date between '$this->date1' and '$this->date2'
                                    and trxtype = 'V')
        group by card_type
        order by 1
```

- Sub-query in fields
- Sub-query in where

---

**[I try this]**:

```
    $conditionsSubQuery['"Auth2"."add_date BETWEEN ? AND ?"'] = array($inicial_date, $final_date);
    $conditionsSubQuery['"Auth2"."trxtype"'] = 'V';

    $db = $this->User->getDataSource();
    $subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
        array(
            'fields'     => array('"Auth2"."origid"'),
            'table'      => 'auth',
            'alias'      => 'Auth2',
            'limit'      => null,
            'offset'     => null,
            'joins'      => array(),
            'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
            'order'      => null,
            'group'      => null
            ),
        $this->Auth
    );

    $subQuery = ' "Auth"."pnref" NOT IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';
    $subQueryExpression = $db->expression($subQuery);

    $conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;
    $conditions[] = array(
        'Auth.date BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($inicial_date, $final_date),
        'OR' => array(
            'Auth.trxtype' => 'S',
            'Auth.trxtype' => 'F'
        ),
        'Auth.user_num' => $user_num
    );

    $fields = array(
        'Auth.card_type',
        "sum (case when Auth.used = 'Y' then (select Auth2.amount from auth Auth2 where Auth2.origid = Auth.pnref and Auth.trxtype = 'D') else Auth.amount end) as Auth.total"
    );

    $group = array('Auth.card_type');
    $order = array(1);

    return $this->Auth->find('all', compact('fields', 'conditions', 'group', 'order'));
```

---

**[ERROR]**

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERRO: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "." LINE 1: ... Auth.trxtype = 'D') else Auth.amount end) as Auth.total, "U... ^

SQL Query: SELECT "Auth"."card_type" AS "Auth__card_type", sum (case when Auth.used = 'Y' then (select Auth2.amount from auth Auth2 where Auth2.origid = Auth.pnref and Auth.trxtype = 'D') else Auth.amount end) as Auth.total, "User"."user_num" AS "User__user_num" FROM "public"."system_users" AS "User" WHERE "Auth"."pnref" NOT IN (SELECT "Auth2"."origid" FROM auth AS "Auth2" WHERE "Auth2"."add_date BETWEEN '2013/02/19 06:00:00' AND '2013/02/22 10:34:17'" AND "Auth2"."trxtype" = 'V' ) AND (("Auth"."date" BETWEEN '2013/02/19 06:00:00' and '2013/02/22 10:34:17') AND ("Auth"."trxtype" = 'F') AND ("Auth"."user_num" = 68)) GROUP BY "Auth"."card_type" ORDER BY "1" ASC

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp
```

---

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Show the code you have tried.

Comment: At least for the subquery (select origid ...) I would keep things simple and use a separate query for that, then use the results of that as a filter/condition for second query

Comment: The problem in the query is pretty obvious that the identifier is being incorrectly associated.  the relevant clause of the error message's query is `"Auth2"."add_date BETWEEN '2013/02/19 06:00:00' AND '2013/02/22 10:34:17'"`  and I doubt you have a boolean column named `"add_date BETWEEN '2013/02/19 06:00:00' AND '2013/02/22 10:34:17'"` so the question really should be limited to CakePHP syntax.

Comment: @ChrisTravers thanks, you right (how much time has passed, so, for now I'm running the raw query with $this->query() method).

Answer (score 1):

Like **@Chris Traveres** comment, is just a syntax error.

> The problem in the query is pretty obvious that the identifier is
>   being incorrectly associated. the relevant clause of the error
>   message's query is "Auth2"."add_date BETWEEN '2013/02/19 06:00:00' AND
>   '2013/02/22 10:34:17'" and I doubt you have a boolean column named
>   "add_date BETWEEN '2013/02/19 06:00:00' AND '2013/02/22 10:34:17'" so
>   the question really should be limited to CakePHP syntax

Problem solved!
Thanks guys.